# User Defined Mean Absolute Error Matrics in CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, conv-neural-network

> I have to compare predicted image from the set of input images with Target images in the CNN model, and my matrics is mean absolute error. but the problem is, if i try to calculate it with default model. it calculates the error value in all pixels of the image, which is averaged the high error values in some location with zero errors in most of the location. here it is like zero dominated MAE,

> i have to define a new MAE fucntion which can be able to find error values at certain location (remote location) where the high error occurs (weighted average)

> Additionally, the remote location is also not constant and it is not known to us. it should be focused by the model itself

> Has anyone face this kind of situations or give any suggestion for this kind of functions?

I am in need to write the user defined function for the remote location monitor and calculate the mean absolute error between target images and the predicted images based on the information frequency.